# Como fazer upload de imagem canvas

Tags: php, jquery, upload, canvas

Eu recebo o resultado de uma imagem através dessa função `this.canvas.toDataURL('png')`, essa função gera a imagem normalmente, os pontos são:

- Como fazer o upload disso para o servidor PHP usando jQuery?
- É a forma correta de se fazer um upload? Não vai me trazer prejuízos por não ser um upload normal, com form input etc..?

Answer (score 0):

> Como fazer o upload disso para o servidor PHP usando jQuery?

É bem simples: Converta seu canvas para `blob` e envie um Ajax, com uma pequena modificação nas configurações.

```
 function ajaxUpload(options) {
      options = $.extend({}, {contentType: false, cache: false, processData: false}, options);
      return $.ajax(options);
 }

 canvas.toBlob(function (blob) {

     var data = new FormData();
     data.append('imagem', blob);

     ajaxUpload({url: '/upload.php', data: data}).success(function () {
        console.log('upload concluído com sucesso');
     });
 });
```

> É a forma correta de se fazer um upload? Não vai me trazer prejuízos por não ser um upload normal, com form input etc..?

Bem, a única diferença que vejo é que você sempre terá que usar ajax. Além do mais, com `input`, geralmente na submissão do upload, envia-se o nome do arquivo, diferente do `blob`, que não tem o nome do arquivo de origem, mas que no caso poderia ser resolvido de maneira simples: Colocando o terceiro parâmetro na chamada de `.append`:

```
  data.append('imagem', blob, 'imagem.jpg')
```

Ademais, não existem "problemas", e sim diferenças.

Comment: Necessidade: não trava a página, pois o blob vai ser construído em 2° plano. De outra maneira eu diria que esse callback é inútil.

Comment: `#toBlob` provavelmente duplica os dados do canvas, enquanto `#toDataURL` faz muito mais. Se tem callback é pq tem obviamente overhead, zZzZz. Não estou dizendo que é pior blobar do que base64ear em momento algum, querido.

Answer (score -1):

**Como fazer o upload disso para o servidor PHP usando jQuery?**

Primeiro é preciso de um arquivo `.php` com função de decodificar a string de base 64 da imagem para adicionar ela em um arquivo no servidor. Então você requisiciona ou posta dados para esse arquivo `.php`, com a imagem em *base64*. Sucesso.

~~ Exemplo ~~

jQuery :

```
$.post({

    data: {

        // Manda a imagem em base 64
        base64: canvas.toDataURL()

    },

    // O arquivo .php com a função citada
    url: "addimage.php"

});
```

PHP :

```
<?php


    // Ignora todos os caracters até a primeira vírgula depois de ";" (semicolon)

    $png = substr(
                $_POST['base64'],
                strpos($_POST['base64'], ";") + 1
    );

    $png = substr(
                $png,
                strpos($png, ",") + 1
    );

    // Cria (ou substitui, caso existente) a imagem no servidor
    file_put_contents('img.png', base64_decode($_POST['base_64']));

?>
```

**É a forma correta de se fazer um upload? Não vai me trazer prejuízos por não ser um upload normal, com form input etc..?**

É comum enviar dados criptografados com base64. Se sua string for muito gigantesca pode ter uma lentidão no servidor, mas isso é raro e difícil de acontecer.

Comment: Observação: O base64 aumentará o tamanho do arquivo em aproximadamente 4 vezes mais, salvo engano.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Você tem razão. Seria bem mais eficiente mandar o código da imagem compressado. Se não me engano `this.canvas.toDataURL('png')` retorna base64, então _deve-se_ desfazer/descriptografar o base64 primeiramente. Outra possibilidade pode ser ler os dados do canvas e transformar numa PNG (usando `DataView` ou `Uint8Array`) manualmente, too.

Comment: Trabalhei em um sistema que precisei fazer uma operação de transformação em `Blob` de várias imagem. Transformar em base64, em grande escala, trava o navegador. O `Blob` não.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Acho que leu meu comentário com pressa. Estava dizendo que o método `#toDataURL` retorna dados criptografados, mas ñ estava pensando que dava para converter canvas num blob. Tbm já mexi um pouco com blob, mas foi nos meus experimentos de HTML5 que hoje ñ faço mais.

Comment: Olá @kai, então não existe criptografia alguma, base64 não é criptografia, é codificação, o Blob é vantajoso para trabalhar com window.URL ou com payload (upload via Ajax por exemplo), base64 no toDataURL creio que funcione até hoje, mesmo que pouco necessário pelos mesmo motivos que outras tecnologias existem, situações especificas que o Blob não vai atender e evitar que aplicações mais antigas feitas baseadas em base64 quebrem, acaso removessem tal funcionalidade da API nativa.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sim, eu entendo que base64 ñ é criptografia, mas blz